# how to update request while sending API using rest assured

Tags: rest-assured

I want to send below as a form-data in API Body for a PUT request:

```
Upload a file(KEY) with "Error.png"(VALUE)
Send text, "MyName"(KEY) with false(VALUE)
```

How to do this using REST-Assured

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you check the REST-Assured documentation or any online tutorial? Why didn't they solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't seem to understand the question completely, but if you're trying to upload a file then you can use

```
given().multiPart("file2", new File("/home/test/some_large_file.bin"))
```

If you wish to send the file as as a RAW data you can use [Tool](https://www.base64encode.org/) to encode the file and send the value in the payload